# Creating grid from 4 sided polygons with equally divided facing sides using FME

Tags: fme-form, vector-grid, polygon-creation

I have a set of polygons, each one comprises 4 sides. Each facing sides are equally divided into segments (right figure).

Is there anyhow to automatically create a grid as shown in the figure on on the left ?

I am using FME

[image]

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS Desktop or FME you wish to ask about in this particular question. If it’s ArcGIS Desktop then also let us know whether you wish to ask about its ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted, the 2DGridCreator will create a grid, but the 2DGridReplacer is the better choice if you want to replace an existing feature.

The difficulty comes when the source data has a rotation, as shown in your image. That's because the 2DGridAccumulator doesn't take account of rotation. So what you'd need to do is rotate the features back to 0 rotation (check for fme_rotation and use the opposite in the Rotator transformer). Then you can use the 2DGridAccumulator. Finally, you would rotate the data back again. However, because it is now a bunch of polygons, you'd need to first group them as an aggregate so they rotated as one.

Here's a workspace I created to do that:

[image]

The left part is mostly setting up data. The right part is the processing you'll need. Notice how I get the x and y coordinates of the lower left and use them to rotate on. I also use x and y in my group bys.

The data starts with a 10 degree rotation. I rotate it by 10 degrees to get it horizontal, add the grid, then rotate it back to the original.

This is the result:

[image]

Notice that I just said to create a 10x10 grid, so this may look slightly different to what you need. But you can change the 2DGridAccumulator settings to adjust that.

Oh, you may want to deaggregate the data at the end, using a Deaggregator transformer, else the divisions will remain as a single block.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you could go about this.

The [**2DGridCreator**](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/2dgridcreator.htm)

> Creates a grid of two-dimensional point or polygon features, at the
> origin and using the offsets specified. Each created feature will have
> a row and column attribute that indicates its position in the grid.

It looks like you may be trying to subdivide parcels of land. Perhaps look at the following transformers:

- [**Offsetter**](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/offsetter.htm?Highlight=offsetter)
- [**CenterlineReplacer**](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/centerlinereplacer.htm?Highlight=centerline)
- [**LineDivider**](https://hub.safe.com/publishers/pacific-spatial-solutions/transformers/linedivider)
- **[LineExtender](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/lineextender.htm?Highlight=extender)**
- **[Clipper](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/clipper.htm?Highlight=cutter)**

I think using these in various combinations may allow you to generate the subdivision patterns if the 2DGridCreator doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

In FME you can use the [Tiler](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/tiler.htm).

In this case the rectangles are set sizes. 2x18
You can group them if there are multiple iterations of the rectangle.

An example using Tiler transformer in FME (2021) workbench.
[image]